# Approximating continuous function vanishing at infinity on product space by product of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am not sure if the question I am asking is proper enough:

Is there any way to approximate any arbitrary function $f(x,y) \in C_{0}(\Omega $ X $ S)$ in the uniform norm by linear combinations of functions of the form $f(x)g(y)$ (which is in $C_{0}(\Omega)$ X $C(S)$)???

[Where: $C_{0}$ denotes the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity]

If yes, then give me the proof!! Otherwise please explain, why it is not possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $\Omega$ and $S$ are both compact, then you consider the algebra
   $$
   D := \{\text{linear combinations of functions of the form } f(x)g(y)\}
   $$
   Check that $D$ satisfies the hypotheses of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, to conclude that $D$ is dense in $C(\Omega\times S)$.
2. Now for the general case, given $f\in C_0(\Omega\times S), \epsilon > 0, \exists K \subset \Omega\times S$ compact such that
   $$
   |f(x,y)| < \epsilon \quad\forall (x,y)\in K
   $$
   Replacing $K$ by $\pi_1(K)\times \pi_2(K)$ [where $\pi_i$ are the coordinate projections], we may assume that $K = A\times B$ where $A\subset \Omega, B\subset S$ are compact. Now restrict $f$ to $A\times B$ and use the first part.